# XAMPP PHP sending emails from to localhost

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm trying to send messages from Localhost to Localhost (Thunderbird account), I'm using XAMPP following this tutorial [How to use mercury ....](http://newcoderslife.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/how-to-use-xampps-mail-server-mercury-mail/)

My php.ini conf is

```
    [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path
```

=

Despite that I still receive the next error

```
 Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 421 Service not available, closing channel.
```

Comment: Do you have the email service service running in your machine?

    421: The service is not available and the connection will be closed.

Comment: How to check if it's running :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue! It was caused by not having a `QUEUE` folder. So I added a folder named `QUEUE` tot the MercuryMail directory `C:\xampp\MercuryMail` and this fixed the problem for me!

Complete path: `C:\xampp\MercuryMail\QUEUE`

Answer (score 2):

1.Install / Properly configure an SMTP server on localhost port 25
2.Change the configuration to point to some other SMTP server that you can connect to

This link may help you...

http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Comment: Can you explain more ? Cause I've already tried this solution before even try using XAMPP and it didn't worked :/